# Problem involving mean value theorem for integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following question:
$\def\pih{{\frac{\pi}2}}$

> Does there exist $\xi \in [\pih,\pi]$ such that $\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\pi}\sqrt{1+x^2}\cos{x}dx = -\sqrt{1+\xi^2}$ ? Prove the result and state all theorems used.

While trying to solve this I've immediately figured out that the mean value theorem for integrals should be applied. Knowing the statement of this theorem it can be proved (this was done as a part of the course) that if $f(x)$ is a continuous function, there exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $\int_a^bf(x)dx = f(c)\cdot(b-a).$ This would imply that there is $ c\in[\pih,\pi]$ such that $\sqrt{1+c^2}\cos(c)\cdot\pih=-\sqrt{1+\xi^2}$. This is basically as far as I'v come to solving this. I can found bounds for $-\sqrt{1+\xi^2}$ from knowing the bounds for $\xi$. Using Desmos I've figured out which point satisfies $c$ but there is no approach that I can think off that definitely proves the required statement. Could someone be able to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

Here, you can use the second mean value theorem for integrals, which states that

If $ f $ is continuous at $ [a,b] $ and $ g $ is integrable at $ [a,b] $ satisfying
$$(\forall x\in [a,b]) \;\; g(x)\ge 0 $$

THEN

$$\exists \xi\in [a,b]\;\; : \;\; \int_a^bfg=f(\xi)\int_a^bg$$

In your case
$$g(x)=-\cos(x)$$

Comment: Is there a way to do it without this theorem? It is not a part of the course and I am not sure that it should be used in that case

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav Yes, in the equality you wrote, you can find  the expression of $\xi$ with respect of $ c $. You square and get $\xi$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Re...welcome :-)...+1.

Comment: @Sebastiano Hi real friend. will Ronaldo go to MU ?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Very very kind friend; I think to the INTER and not to the MU or Juventus=Rubentus ahahhahah.

Comment: @Sebastiano Best wishes to You and Inter Milano.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah My sincere regards with all my heart.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah But the function is transcendental, I can't find c in close form

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah but shouldn't I prove that $\xi$ is in the required interval?

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav Right .  You can do it .

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah How do I do that if I cannot analytically solve the equality for c? Pardon my ignorance, I really  have no clue...

Comment: Right... got myself confused. Thanks